# Shopify creates a product id for each size?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I had a small query regarding bulk product upload in Shopify. Shopify creates a product id for each size. Which means every product appears 7 times (XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL) in the CSV sheet. This increases the size of the CSV sheet as we have to fill each detail 7 times for the same product. Is there a plugin/app or a work around to restrict the product information to 1 row per SKU?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fill each detail 7 times. You need to fill it only for the first variant. Shopify will get the title, body and other information that belongs to the product entity. But you still need to keep variant rows in the CSV file as products and variants are different entities in Shopify. For example, these rows keep information about variant options, in your case, these are sizes: XS, S, M, ...

Shopify groups variants by the first column - handle. It should be same for all variants.

Then you have `Title`, `Body (HTML)`, `Vendor`, `Type`, `Tags` and `Published` columns. The data from these fields belong to product entities and should be filled for the first variant row if you have data for these fields. But it can be skipped for other variants rows.

So, just ignore these rows unless you need to update any information that is related to variants.